# Inserting jpeg letterhead layout into a word document - Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-word, conversion

I have been provided with a .jpeg of a letterhead layout by my graphic designer who operates in Mac - I need to convert this to a Word document without losing the integrity of the logo.  By simply inserting the logo into the header portion and the footer portion, it does not print well at all.  As most of my letters are sent via email I need to improve this.

I am operating in Windows 8 by the way.  Everything I see and read when trying to research this does not seem to have the same layout as me.